# Problema con collapse en bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">
<a  class="nodecoration panel-title lead" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#uno" href="#uno">Uno</a>

<a  class="nodecoration panel-title lead" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#dos" href="#dos">Dos</a>
</div>

<div id="uno" class="panel-collapse collapse">
<div class="panel-body">
Uno
</div>
</div>

<div id="dos" class="panel-collapse collapse">
<div class="panel-body">
Dos
</div>
</div>
</div>
<br>

<script>
$(".panel-heading").hover(
 function() {
    $('.panel-collapse').collapse('show');
  }, function() {
    $('.panel-collapse').collapse('hide');
  }
);
</script>


    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Logro hacer que al pasar el mouse se active pero me muestra los dos juntos

/---------------------------------/

estoy tratando de hacer un submenu usando collapse. Es algo asi:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#uno" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">Uno</a>

<a class="btn btn-primary" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#dos" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">Dos</a>


<div class="collapse" id="uno">
<div class="well">
Uno
</div>
</div>

<div class="collapse" id="dos">
<div class="well">
Dos
</div>
</div>
```

El problema es que si doy click en el uno, abre normalmente, pero si doy click en el dos se cierra el uno y no abre el dos al menos que haga click otra vez. Se entiende? Espero me ayuden. Gracias

Comment: que version de bootstrap estas usando?

Comment: Es importante agregar detalles al realizar preguntas, como el que comenta WFgo , revisa [ask], saludos!

Comment: gracias, la version 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahora si ahi queda la solucion a tu problema

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    
   <p>
  <a class="btn btn-primary btn-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" href="#multiCollapseExample1" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="multiCollapseExample1">Toggle first element</a>
  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-collapse" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#multiCollapseExample2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="multiCollapseExample2">Toggle second element</button>
</p>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="collapse multi-collapse" id="multiCollapseExample1">
      <div class="card card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="collapse multi-collapse" id="multiCollapseExample2">
      <div class="card card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
$(function(){  

    $(document).ready(function(){ 
  $('.collapse').on('show.bs.collapse',function(){
  $('.collapse.show').collapse('toggle');
  });
 });

});
</script>


    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gracias Willian...

Answer (score 1):

Deberias utilizar el accordion:

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  
  
   <div id="accordion">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>

    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingThree">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar una explicación a tu respuesta? Gracias ;)

Comment: Gracias, pero no es justamente eso. Hace lo mismo que el que hice yo. El objetivo es que cuando haga click en el boton **dos**, el **uno** deje de aparecer.

Comment: Esta solución es para la versión 4 y no para la versión 3.X de bootstrap.

Comment: Entonces deberias usar accordion @Seva ya edite mi respuesta, ahi esta el ejemplo con accordion

Answer (score 1):

En la version 3 tenes que hacer uso de los eventos que te proporciona bootstrap

La solución es ocultar el div collapse visible. Esto es posible en el evento show

```
$('.collapse').on('show.bs.collapse',function(){
    $('.collapse.in').collapse('toggle');
});
```

Aca esta el fiddle funcionando [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/stv3Ly93/5/)

Los evento de del collapse de bootstrap los podes ver [aca](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#collapse-methods)

Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias, voy a leer un poco mas de java porque esto aca no termina. Gracias nuevamente

Comment: Pregunta: hay alguna funcion que permita que se despliegue sin hacer click?

Comment: @Seva se puede llegar a implementar el mismo comportamiento con el evento hover. Esto es javascript (JS), no java. Saludos

Comment: Entiendo. Gracias

Comment: Encontre algo como esto: `$(".panel-heading").hover(
 function() {
    $('.panel-collapse').collapse('show');
  }, function() {
    $('.panel-collapse').collapse('hide');
  }
);` - el problema ahora es como el anterior